# Dispose called by Component.Finalize() on non-UI thread - does this mean Dispose methods always have to be thread safe?

Tags: winforms

I checked which thread my Dispose(bool) methods get called on. When the app is running, it is always the UI thread that calls Dispose, say when clicking on the [x] to close a Form. But when I close the whole app, many Dispose methods get called on a (single) different thread. When I dump the stack trace, I see that they all get called from
System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize().

Does that mean all my Dispose methods need to be made thread-safe? Or is WinForms guaranteeing that the UI thread won't touch these objects any more and does it also establish some kind of "happened-before" relationship between the UI thread and the one that's now finalizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the finalizer works on a separate thread. Usually this is no problem, because when an Object is finalized it is not reachable by any user thread (like the UI thread) anymore. So, you usually do not have to be thread-safe within your finalizer.

Comment: "Usually" sounds a bit vague, but if WinForms guarantees that the original UI thread is not run any more at the time the finalizer thread does its work, then I'm fine with that.

Comment: Well, with usually I just meant that there can be synchronization issues in your Dispose method, e.g. when you try to access shared resources in it... But it *is* guaranteed that all other thread are suspended when the finalizer is running.